# Can GIS SE lower its number of unanswered questions from 2,000+?

Tags: discussion

This may not even be a concern with the users, and there's probably a valid reason, but the answer ratio on GIS is kinda low **(84%)** compared to other Stack sites with similar traffic (but not *that* much lower). As of this posting, **2,082 questions** on GIS have no upvoted answers. Being inexperienced with the GIS community both here and at large, I'd like to know if this seems normal. Are these questions bad questions with bad answers? Are they about obsolete software?

From my experience working with Stack Exchange, we tend to see this as a problem; it'd be easy to assume from the number that a lot of users come here, ask a question, and don't get a decent answer (or an answer at all). **I do understand that that most likely does not apply for GIS.** I just want to know if you, the loyal users, think the low answer ratio is a problem to be fixed! And truthfully, from my perspective this is a very healthy site, and this low-ish answer ratio is the one area of improvement.

If you want to help lower the number of unanswered questions:

- [Check out these high voted questions with no upvoted answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)
- [Check out these questions with no answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)

I would like to see if we can get GIS's answer percentage up to 90% over the next month. Looking at the questions in the links above and giving them the once over is a good place to start.